# Converting Date to ISO Week of Year in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

This is the query I am running:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(fullvisitorid), device.deviceCategory
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxx.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01'),TIMESTAMP('2014-12-31')) GROUP BY date, device.deviceCategory
```

This returns date and total users for each day broken out by device. Is there a way to convert this date (individual day) into ISO week of year? Ex: if the day was 2014-01-01 it would be bucketed into "1" for week 1.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do this. One is using EXTRACT:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-06-25')
```

The other is using FORMAT_TIMESTAMP:

```
FORMAT_DATE('%V', DATE '2018-06-25')
```

EXTRACT has the benefit that it works the same for date, datetime and timestamp fields. Downside is that it has [very limited output options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract_1), but one of them is isoweek so it serves your purpose.

FORMAT_DATE comes with a family of functions (FORMAT_TIMESTAMP, FORMAT_DATETIME, FORMAT_TIME) but you have to use the right one depending on your data type. On the plus side, you can do [very specific transformations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp) using combinations of [supported format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has WEEK function - so

```
SELECT WEEK(CAST('2014-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP)),
       WEEK(CAST('2014-12-31' AS TIMESTAMP))
```

returns 1 and 53 respectively.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to an entire date range? So if I have 6/1/14 - 12/31/14 it will add ISO week of year for the corresponding date? (6/7/14 would be shown as 23, 10/14/14 as 42) etc.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but if you have column ts in a table T which has values from 6/1/14 to 12/31/14, you will simply use the following: ``SELECT ts, WEEK(ts) AS wk FROM T``

Comment: This is not ISO week